# PS Move sample code, got it working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, playstation3

I am trying to make use of the PS Move-me sample code made available at:
http://code.google.com/p/moveme/
I am using Visual Studio Express 2010. After importing the C# solution into VS (older version). I have also built and added the requested OpenTK dlls.
Despite indicating to build in x86 and building all (was a suggested solution at the PS forum from 2011). I still get a situation where the sample code runs, but no data is received for the Move-me controller is received by the code. Making the samples a little rubbish. The only action I can get the code to do is connect to the Move-me server on the PS3, rumble the controller, and calibrate the controller. No data returns.
I am stumpped! I want to use the PS Move-me as a mouse controller for an investigation I am doing surrounding pointing devices like the PS Move Me.

Really appreciate any input on this. Cant see how to progress with this.

Comment: After much searching and prodding, it transpires that the visual studio version and conversion mechanism was causing some funky issues with the compilation. As the code was intended to be built x86 32 bit, after converting the project to the latest visual studio express for c#, selecting the correct target platform on a 64 bit machine does not have the correct affect. In short I gave up on the Sony sample code and used a Java implementation (http://code.google.com/p/move-me-java/) to write a mouse pointer using the move.me server on PS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching and prodding, it transpires that the visual studio version and conversion mechanism was causing some funky issues with the compilation. As the code was intended to be built x86 32 bit, after converting the project to the latest visual studio express for c#, selecting the correct target platform on a 64 bit machine does not have the correct affect. In short I gave up on the Sony sample code and used a Java implementation (code.google.com/p/move-me-java) to write a mouse pointer using the move.me server on PS3